# Use reflection to determine the classes an Interator function could yield?

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I'm trying to write a program to help analyze/document one of our applications. 
I'd like to be able to get a list of all the objects that an Interator Function could possibly yield. For example, I'd like to be able to run the analysis on this code and end up with the names "Class A", "Class B" and "Class C":

```
Public Iterator Function Sample(status As Boolean) As IEnumerable
    If status = True Then
        Yield New ClassA
    Else
        Yield New ClassB
        Yield New ClassC
    End If
End Function
```

Is this possible using reflection or maybe Mono.Cecil?

Comment: Will such iterators always be as straightforward as the one you've shown (every `Yield` statement directly creating the returned object)? If not, I'd say it's either `Object` and anything derived from it, or you have to solve the Halting problem.

Comment: Yes. There is a list of possible classes that could be returned and I'll have access to this list.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is possible.

Imagine an iterator that pulls records from a database query, and uses the Factory pattern to construct objects from those records that implement a common interface, but are still different concrete types. This iterator could create any number of objects belonging to many different types, and as the application changes over time those types could change, too.

Comment: There is a set list of objects that could be returned. And I have access to this list. (This is part of a CQRS setup. The command handler is yielding a list of classes that represent the events that need to be processed.)